# From Visual Studio project to file .exe (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, exe

I have already finished a Qt Application (cheekers game). I would that my work could run on others PC and out of Visual Studio like a commercial app. I already found the file .exe that is in the directory "Realese" but it doesn't work. What I have to do?

using cmd I have this, but it still doesn't run

C:\Users\Giorgio>c:/Qt/5.5/msvc2012/bin/windeployqt.exe Desktop/Progetto_Dama/progetto/Release/dama.exe
C:\Users\Giorgio\Desktop\Progetto_Dama\progetto\Release\dama.exe 32 bit, release executable

Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicon.dll

Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets

All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets

To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets

Warning: Cannot find Visual Studio installation directory, VCINSTALLDIR is not set.

Updating Qt5Core.dll.

Updating Qt5Gui.dll.

Updating Qt5Svg.dll.

Updating Qt5Widgets.dll.

Updating libGLESV2.dll.

Updating libEGL.dll.

Updating D3Dcompiler_46.dll.

Updating opengl32sw.dll.Patching Qt5Core.dll...Creating directory iconengines.

Updating qsvgicon.dll.

Creating directory imageformats.

Updating qdds.dll.

Updating qgif.dll.

Updating qicns.dll.

Updating qico.dll.

Updating qjp2.dll.

Updating qjpeg.dll.

Updating qmng.dll.

Updating qsvg.dll.

Updating qtga.dll.

Updating qtiff.dll.

Updating qwbmp.dll.

Updating qwebp.dll.

Creating directory platforms.

Updating qwindows.dll.

Creating C:\Users\Giorgio\Desktop\Progetto_Dama\progetto\Release\translations...

Creating qt_ca.qm...

Creating qt_cs.qm...

Creating qt_de.qm...

Creating qt_en.qm...

Creating qt_fi.qm...

Creating qt_fr.qm...

Creating qt_he.qm...

Creating qt_hu.qm...

Creating qt_it.qm...

Creating qt_ja.qm...

Creating qt_ko.qm...

Creating qt_lv.qm...

Creating qt_ru.qm...

Creating qt_sk.qm...

Creating qt_uk.qm...

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: The problem is caused by the dlls of the Qt library, I recommend you to look for the windeployqt utility, then open a cmd in the folder of your executable, and execute: `path/of/windeployqt.exe .`

Comment: Look at that point after windeployqt.exe is important.

Answer (score 0):

But if eyllanesc's answer isn't working for you, you can usually find the missing .dll's from trial and error i.e. when you try to launch the .exe file it probable tells you some library is missing. If you keep copying and pasting each library into the same folder as the .exe file, your app will eventually run (after you've added the correct library that your .exe is asking for it will ask for another one, upon trying to execute the file, until you have added all of them). I'm not familiar with the visual studios version of qt, so I'm not sure which directory your .dll's will be under. For me it is /Qt/version/Mingw*version*/bin/ . But that is while using the mingw default kit. For vs's I believe it will be C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\winrt_x64_msvc2017\bin with the relevant version numbers.

Comment: unfortunally when i run the .exe the error message says: "...searching for reason" and after some minutes it asks to me to open visual studio debbugger